# Why is CDE only loading a blank screen for all of my .XML descriptors?

Tags: eclipse, uima, ruta

Any time I try to use the Component Descriptor Editor to view a descriptor file, I get a blank page instead of the UI.

I tried uninstalling/re-installing the Workbench. I also updated all of my UIMA software to 2.10.3 and UIMAfit is at 2.4.0.

The screen is blank, gray background. The tab text is also empty. I can open the files with the XML or text editors.

Also - I found this in the log...

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-07-08 10:47:10.069
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor' from bundle '478'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/custom/TableTree
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:1015)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:781)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:752)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:746)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:730)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$1.handleEvent(PartServiceImpl.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.lambda$0(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:6018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElementGen(ElementContainerImpl.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:652)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:616)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:404)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1240)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3209)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.lambda$9(WorkbenchPage.java:3114)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3112)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3083)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenWithMenu.openEditor(OpenWithMenu.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenWithMenu.lambda$0(OpenWithMenu.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5874)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1400)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:5138)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4663)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1173)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:660)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1468)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1441)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/custom/TableTree
    at org.apache.uima.taeconfigurator.editors.MultiPageEditor.parseSourceInner(MultiPageEditor.java:1003)
    at org.apache.uima.taeconfigurator.editors.MultiPageEditor.parseSource(MultiPageEditor.java:997)
    at org.apache.uima.taeconfigurator.editors.MultiPageEditor.init(MultiPageEditor.java:978)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.initialize(EditorReference.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:340)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:1001)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:966)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:411)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.custom.TableTree cannot be found by org.apache.uima.desceditor_2.10.3
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:155)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 86 more
```

Answer (score 1):

CDE is not compatible with this version of Eclipse. It needs an older one. The mentioned class was removed in 4.12/2019-06.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=475833

Comment: Understood. Hoping it will get fixed to be compatible.

Comment: Please open a bug in the UIMA issue tracker: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/UIMA/issues